# Hiding products with a specific tag from WooCommerce main shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to hide products with a specific tag from WooCommerce main shop page but not from this same tag dedicated page.

To be clearer, see https//www.popito.fr.

I would like to remove products tagged "pré-commande" from here: https://popito.fr/boutique/ but not from here: https://popito.fr/etiquette-produit/pre-commande/.

Is it doable? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste the following snippet in your child theme's functions.php

```
function exclude_specific_tag( $q ) {
    if (is_shop()){
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'pré-commande' ), // write the tag name to remove in between the ''
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'exclude_specific_tag' );
```

Comment: Thanks! It gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/popiatch/public_html/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/functions.php on line 46 (last line of my functions.php)...

Comment: I've updated the snippet, this should work.

Comment: then you can accept the answer so it's helpful for another users too.

Comment: One last thing though: it works perfectly except for search results where products with the "pré-commande" tag don't appear too...

Comment: you can try to replace (is_shop()) by (is_shop() && !isset($_GET['s']))

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed :-)